# Increase Number in TextView

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to implement a plus button into my app that will increase the `TextView` number by 1 each time the button is pressed.

The problem that I am having is that when I press the button, it displays an integer value, but does not increase when I click the button again. It stays the same.

How can I continue to increase the value each time I press the "+" button.

Here is my `ViewHolder` code that contains my `onClickListener`:

```
public int numItems = 0;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Image);
            mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            mNumberItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfItems);

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int totalItems = (int) Math.ceil(numItems + 1);
                    mNumberItem.setText("Items: " +  totalItems);
                }
            });

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mNumberItem.setText("Test");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment `numItems`.

```
mNumberItem.setText("Items: " +  ++numItems);
```